# Does C++ map erase elements in loop invalidates iterator? (C++03)

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, c++03, erase

I have this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdint.h>

class Table
{
public:
  std::map<uint32_t, std::string> m_map;

  typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::string>::iterator Iterator_t;
  typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::string>::const_iterator ConstIterator_t;

  Table () : m_map () { }

  void
  Erase (Iterator_t entry_it, const std::string & reason)
  {
    std::cout << reason << " " << entry_it->first << ":" << entry_it->second << "\n";
    m_map.erase (entry_it);
//        m_map.erase (entry_it->first);
  }

  bool
  Insert (const uint32_t & key, const std::string & value)
  {
    ConstIterator_t found_it = m_map.find (key);

    if (found_it != m_map.end ())
      {
        std::cout << "Key [" << key << "] already exists\n";
        return false;
      }

    m_map.insert (std::make_pair (key, value));
    std::cout << key << ":" << value << " inserted\n";
    return true;
  }

  void
  Print () const
  {
    std::cout << "Table: ";
    for (ConstIterator_t it = m_map.begin (); it != m_map.end (); ++it)
      {
        std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << " ";
      }
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  void
  Purge ()
  {
    for (Iterator_t it = m_map.begin (); it != m_map.end (); ++it)
      {
        if (it->second.length () <= 4)
          {
            Erase (it, "Erase entry ");
          }
      }
  }
};

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  Table table;

  table.Insert (1, "one");
  table.Insert (2, "two");
  table.Insert (3, "three");
  table.Insert (4, "four");
  table.Insert (5, "nine");
  table.Insert (6, "six");
  table.Insert (7, "seven");
  table.Insert (8, "eight");
  table.Insert (9, "nine");
  table.Print ();
  std::cout << "\n";

  table.Purge ();
  table.Print ();
  std::cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
1:one inserted
2:two inserted
3:three inserted
4:four inserted
5:five inserted
6:six inserted
7:seven inserted
8:eight inserted
9:nine inserted
Table: 1:one 2:two 3:three 4:four 5:nine 6:six 7:seven 8:eight 9:nine 

Erase entry  1:one
Erase entry  2:two
Erase entry  4:four
Erase entry  6:six
Erase entry  9:nine
Table: 3:three 5:five 7:seven 8:eight
```

As you can see the `5:five` should have been erased, but it wasn't. I don't fully understand why.

The two overloads of `m_map.erase ()` I tried produce the same result. And I couldn't find a version of `std::remove_if` for maps.

I must point out that this **has to be in C++03**, and I found only answers for C++11/14. Can you please tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sam answered, [std::map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase()) will invalidate the iterator to the erased element. After that the invalid iterator is used for increment operation in for loop, which is undefined behavior.

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

To solve it, since C++11 you could use the return value of `erase`, which is the iterator following the removed element. But for C++03, you have to do that manually. e.g.

```
class Table
{
public:
  ...    
  void
  Purge ()
  {
    for (Iterator_t it = m_map.begin (); it != m_map.end (); )
      {
        if (it->second.length () <= 4)
          {
            Erase (it++, "Erase entry ");
          }
        else
          {
            ++it;
          }
      }
  }
};
```

The point of the above code is that the increment is performed before `erase` happens (while `it` is still a valid iterator). And we take advantage of the fact that `it++` will return the original value of `it`. Thus the evaluation order would be: (1) `it` is incremented; (2) the original value of `it` is passed to `erase`; (3) the element is `erase`d.

Comment: `std::map::erase` does not return an iterator in c++03: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair enough. Answer revised.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick answers. 

If I understand the new code correctly, `Erase (it++, "Erase entry ");` sends the current value of the iterator `it` and then increase it (move to the next entry), so it points to a valid entry in the map even if the prior entry is erased. Am I correct?

Comment: @SteveB. Yes it's correct. More precisely, the evaluation order is: (1) `it` is incremented; (2) the original value of `it` is passed to `erase`; (3) that element is erased. The point is that the increment is performed before `erase` (when `it` is still a valid iterator). And we take advantage of the fact that `it++` will return the original value before increment.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is undefined behavior.

`erase()` invalidates the iterator to the removed map value. The loop then attempts to increment the invalidated iterator. It doesn't matter if `erase()` is called directly inside the loop, or in a function called from the loop. Either way, this is undefined behavior. This is true for both C++03, C++11, and C++14. This is, fundamentally, how maps work.